# rails make query better

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, performance, activerecord

In my table schema
I have “listeners” table connect to “devices” table (one to many)
Now I need to search on listener table but with the devices.id field

My problem is that the 2 table should have many of records (more than 1,000,000) and I afraid that my query will crash the application
My problem is on the in select
I want to know what can I do to make this query better

My full query on gist https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8623345

```
limit = 10
@listeners = Listener.all
@total_count = @listeners.count
@sEcho = params[:sEcho]

**@listeners =@listeners.where(" (listeners.name like ?) or (listeners.email like ?) or (countries.name like ?) or   (listeners.city like ?)  or   (listeners.id in (select listener_id from devices where id = ?))", "%#{params[:sSearch]}%", "%#{params[:sSearch]}%" , "%#{params[:sSearch]}%","%#{params[:sSearch]}%","#{params[:sSearch]}") if params[:sSearch].present?**

order_by ="listeners.id asc"
@listeners = @listeners.includes(:devices)
@listeners = @listeners.includes(:country) 
@count = @listeners.count
@listeners = @listeners.order(order_by)
@listeners = @listeners.limit(limit).offset(params[:iDisplayStart])
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use kaminari or will paginate for pagination and you are making this more complex this is the shortest form i think so:

```
Listener.includes(:devices, country).where(" (listeners.name like ?) or (listeners.email like ?) or (countries.name like ?) or   (listeners.city like ?)  or   (listeners.id in (select listener_id from devices where id = ?))", "%#{params[:sSearch]}%", "%#{params[:sSearch]}%" , "%#{params[:sSearch]}%","%#{params[:sSearch]}%","#{params[:sSearch]}").limit(limit).offset(params[:iDisplayStart]||1).order(:id)
```